# In Roll20, how can I check whether my character's ability scores have the racial ability score increase included?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, roll20

A while back I rolled the ability scores for my character. However, I can't remember at all if racial ability score increases were already somehow added to my ability scores.

**Is there a way for me to see my raw ability scores on Roll20, or is there another way to figure out if I already added them?**

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

## Your character sheet shows your ability scores after any bonuses

Roll20 doesn't keep track of racial ability score increases or ASIs; the numbers displayed on your character sheet are your ability scores after such changes.

#### Without using the Charactermancer

If you've entered the ability scores manually (i.e. without using Roll20's Charactermancer), then you'd need to manually enter the final numbers you'd have after adding any racial ability score increases/changes - Roll20 won't add them for you. And when you get ASIs, you'd have to manually increase the number yourself.

If your ability scores look identical to your rolls, with the racial ability score increases not applied, then you (or your DM) forgot to add them yourself before entering them in.

#### Using the Charactermancer

If you do use the [Charactermancer](https://wiki.roll20.net/Charactermancer_(D%26D_Fifth_Edition)), then during character creation, it does prompt you to first choose your race and class first, and then enter your ability scores (determined using whatever method your group uses). If you enter the ability scores in the Charactermancer here, then it is inclusive of any ability score increases from your chosen race (assuming you pick a race you have access to via the SRD or by purchasing that content on Roll20).

However, after you go through all the steps, it takes you to your character sheet, where only the final result is displayed for the ability scores; it doesn't retain the original ability scores before those bonuses (anywhere that's accessible to users, at least).

In addition, [the Charactermancer can also be used when leveling up a character](http://blog.roll20.net/post/181846550085/charactermancer-levels-up-go-beyond-level-1) - including at those levels where you get an ASI. Again, though, it takes you back to your updated character sheet afterward, with only the final result retained.

---

No matter how you create and level up the character on Roll20, the displayed ability scores when looking at your character sheet are the final result. There's no way to see the original rolls in the sheet itself. (If you rolled them in that game room, though, they'll still be in the full chat log.)